# Do some genes follow Rock-Paper-Scissors model of dominance?

Tags: genetics, allele

Assuming there are at least 3 alleles of the gene $G$ in total - $G_R$, $G_S$ and $G_P$ - is there any gene for which the following is true?

- $G_R$ is more dominant than $G_S$.
- $G_S$ is more dominant than $G_P$.
- $G_P$ is more dominant than $G_R$.

Comment: Note that the "rock-paper-scissors pattern" is more formally known as a "non-transitive relation". You may be familiar with a transitive relation, where if A>B and B>C, then A>C. If instead A>B and B>C, but A<C (C>A), then it's known as a non-transitive relation, like the one you describe here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick search gives this same question in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/7jay7y/are_there_any_rockpaperscissorsgenes/) Reddit post.

Apparently, there is not yet an existing example of such dominance of three alleles on one another.

That said, if you're interested in rock-paper-scissor patterns in nature, then you will be interested in the [side-blotched lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-blotched_lizard). It has three genetically encoded male "sexes", that also determines their behaviour. At a population level, the three sexes follow a rock-paper-scissor pattern of successful sexual competition, in that orange-throated individuals can outcompete yellow-throated ones, which can outcompete blue-throated ones, which can outcome orange-throated ones. [A simulation has been carried out](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28385667) to model the underlying genetics, but that model doesn't involve a rock-paper-scissors pattern of genetic dominance.

Comment: @ruakh You mean "outcompete", not "outcome".

Comment: @CJDennis: Yeah, I noticed that typo a few days after proposing the edit. (I also should have written something like "[...] but to be clear, that model [...]" instead of just "but that model".) But given that the edit took almost two weeks to get approved, it doesn't seem worth proposing a new edit just to fix such minor issues. :-/

Comment: @ruakh Too late now, but you can edit your edit before its approved.

Comment: @CJDennis: Oh! Oops. Good to know. :-P